# Borel-Moore Homology and Kunneth Formula

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Given two algebraic varieties $X$ and $Y$.
It is true that $H^{BM}_n(X\times Y) \cong \bigoplus_{i+j=n} H^{BM}_i (X)\otimes_\mathbb{Q} H^{BM}_i(Y)$.

I think that the proof is similar to the one in singular homology.
Does someone know a possible reference for this formula in Borel-Moore Homology?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, isn't Borel-Moore Homology defined for manifolds, not for varieties (i.e. the analytic structure is used, which is not available on an algebraic variety unless you perform some sort of analytification). But with this caveat: Borel-Mooore Homology coincides with singular homology for compact spaces, so in particular the Kunneth Formula you've written down must hold when the variety is compact. Now since Borel-Moore Homology is defined in the locally compact setting, we can extend to the general case by gluing.

Comment: When I've had BM homology defined to me in the past, it was always just the relative singular homology of the pair $(\bar{X},\bar{X}\setminus X)$ where $\bar{X}$ is the one-point compactification of $X$. There's no analytic condition necessary as far as I know, just local compactness.

Comment: That's precisely what I mean: one-point compactification is roughly an "analytic" procedure, because it doesn't exhibit $\overline{X}$ as a variety - just as a set with a (potentially non-Zariski) topology.

One could take $\overline{X}$ to be the smooth compactification of $X$, in which case you need a different set of hypotheses on $X$ (e.g. the base field must be perfect to ensure uniqueness), but in any case local compactness doesn't play a role in smooth compactification.

Comment: Sorry yes, I was thinking of local compactness only because it preserves Hausdorff under compactification (but that doesn't matter here anyway). The main point I wanted to make was that there is no caveat needed. Singular homology is defined for any topological space and so then is BM homology, even if the compactification isn't a variety.

Comment: Now look back at my original answer and see if it makes sense. When we do BM homology, we're no longer in the land of varieties cut out by algebraic equations: we're doing manifold theory, most likely in the Euclidean topology as opposed to the Zariski.